# sql server - insert if not exist else update

Tags: sql-server

I have here a list of 100 types of item flavor. Then I have a table where I need a record for every item in every flavor. So if I have 50 items, I need 100 records for each of the 50 items in this table_A. so there will be a total of 100x50 records in this table at the end.

What I have now is a random mix of data and I know I don't have a record for each type of flavor for every item.

What I need help with is, an idea/algorithm so solve this problem. pseudo code would do. I have a table with all possible flavors (tbl_flavor) and a table with all 50 items (tbl_items). These two will dictate what needs to be put in table_A which is basically an inventory.

Please advise.

Comment: Could you update your question with the code you have so far?  It'll be easier to help if we see what you've tried so far and where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: With CTE as (Select A.*, B.* from A Cross Join B) Insert into FinalTable Select * from CTE where CTE.Key not exists (Select Key from FinalTable)  the cross join gives you a complete set of the 50*the 100.  The not exits will exclude all those you already have in the table.  Or easier, just delete everything from the table and insert everything from the cross join (unless you need to preserve other attributes)

Comment: Use Merge clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, a SQL Server [`EXCEPT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) query will help.

As already pointed out in the comments, here's how to get the matrix of items and flavors:

```
SELECT Items.Item, Flavors.Flavor
FROM Items
CROSS JOIN Flavors
```

Here's how to get the matrix of items and flavors, omitting the combinations that are already in your other table.

```
SELECT Items.Item, Flavors.Flavor
  FROM Items
  CROSS JOIN Flavors
EXCEPT SELECT Item, Flavor
  FROM Table_A
```

So the INSERT becomes:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A (Item, Flavor)
SELECT Items.Item, Flavors.Flavor
  FROM Items
  CROSS JOIN Flavors
EXCEPT SELECT Item, Flavor
  FROM Table_A
```

This query is untested because I'm not 100% sure about the question. If you post more detail I'll test it.

Comment: Thanks. This addresses exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I do have one issue with the query. When I try the following, it fails with an error message:All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions ....... insert into table_A (flavor_id, prod_id, available_qty, lastupdated, lastupdatedby) 
 select fla.flavor_id, sp.product_id, 200, getdate(), 'User1'
 from Flavors fla
  cross join products sp
 where sp.product_cd in (select product_cd from list_products)
 and fla.flavor_id in (select fla_value from tblX where fla_value = 'Y')
 except select pl.flavor_id, pl.product_id from table_A pl

Comment: in my insert, I have to provide a lastupdated at least. Now the issue is, if I add an extra field in my select and except, it will get me wrong result set. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can tackle this sort of problem. Here is psuedocode for one of those ways.

```
Update table
set Col1 = SomeValue
where MyKeys = Mykeys

if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
begin
    Insert table
    (Cols)
    Values
    (Vals)
end
```

Or you can use MERGE. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: However, Merge is hard to troubleshoot later when you have an error. I far prefer the Update Insert method. And it is important to do the update before the insert to avoid both inserting and updating the new records.

Comment: Agreed. Even though is the "old style" approach I find it a lot easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
UPDATE MyTable
        SET
        ColumnToUpdate = NewValue
        WHERE EXISTS
        (
            SELECT
                1
                FROM TableWithNewValue
                    WHERE ColumnFromTable1 = MyTable.ColumnName
        )

INSERT INTO MyTable
(
    Column1,
    Column2,
    ...
    ColumnN
)
SELECT
    Value1,
    Value2,
    ...
    ValueN
    FROM TableWithNewValue
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT
                1
                FROM MyTable 
                    WHERE ColumnName = TableWithNewValue.ColumnFromTable1 
        )
```